# Gridview format issue after show message

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, merge

I have a Gridview, and one button.
when i click button then show message, but after that my Gridview's format is not correct as before.

please view more in below picture:
[Gridview incorrect format after close message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrvls.jpg)

I using this code below to show message:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Đã tồn tại nguồn đơn " & name & ". Bạn không thể tạo thêm được nguồn đơn này nữa')</script>")
Return
```

=> How to keep previos format?

This code below i using:

```
Private Sub grvData_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grvData.RowCommand
lblError.Text = String.Empty
Dim commandNameType As String = String.Empty
Try
    If e.CommandName = "Insert" Then
        commandNameType = "thêm"
        Dim txtName As TextBox = DirectCast(grvData.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewName"), TextBox)
        Dim cboStatus As DropDownList = DirectCast(grvData.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlNewStatus"), DropDownList)

        lblError.Text = String.Empty
        Try
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text) Then
                Return
            End If
            Dim pSource As New TblPetitionSource
            pSource.Name = txtName.Text
            pSource.Lastupdate = Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
            pSource.StatusFlag = 1
            pSource.UpdateBy = "ADMIN"

            Dim db As New ProcuracyDataContext
            Dim lst = (From p In db.TblPetitionSource Where p.Name = txtName.Text Select p).ToList()
            If lst.Count > 0 Then
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Đã tồn tại nguồn đơn . Bạn không thể tạo thêm được nguồn đơn này nữa')</script>")
                Return
            End If

            db.TblPetitionSource.InsertOnSubmit(pSource)
            db.SubmitChanges()
            BindData()

        Catch ex As Exception
            lblError.Text = ex.Message
        End Try
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    lblError.Text = "Lỗi không " & commandNameType & " được bản ghi này <br />" & ex.Message
End Try
```

End Sub

This is my code using for MergeCells:

```
Private Sub grvData_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grvData.RowDataBound
   Try
       If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
           e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1)
           e.Row.Cells(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1).ColumnSpan = 2
           e.Row.Cells(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1).Text = "Thao tác"
       End If
       If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
           e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1)
           e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1)
           e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1)
           e.Row.Cells(e.Row.Cells.Count - 1).ColumnSpan = 4
       End If
   Catch ex As Exception
       Throw New Exception(ex.Message, ex)
   End Try
```

End Sub

Could you see more detail at these files:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6NcrBkoDTV5TV9QcFFUWUpnTFk

and the form after click button:
[Web form after click button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjr3u.jpg)

Thanks you so much!

Comment: I think you are missing some code. What's happening before it shows the message? I guess the control line is pushed down to the next row.

Comment: Hi Clijsters!
I already edit my question with more informations, please help me.

Comment: The strange but not so strange thing happens at your `InsertOnSubmit()` call. After this (or at it) you have to reformat the row to merge the cells like before (or hide the borders). What are `ProcuracyDataContext` or `TblPetitionSource`? Because I have problems to understand why you are `new`ing them.

Comment: Hi @Clijsters  
`ProcuracyDataContext ` is database class mapping with Linq.  
`TblPetitionSource` is DataTable class mapping with Linq.  
I try call function `BindData()` to raise event `grvData_RowDataBound` for reformat the row to merge the cells like before. but it's not ok.  
and also all controls in my form lost format as height, width of controls increase, auto line break,.. some thing like that.

Comment: Could you post a link to your Designer.vb file? This file has the lines of code to format your gridView. You have tu reuse them.

Comment: Hi @Clijsters! I already post my code using for merge cells. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try to manually execute the code block, which lays in the eventhandler or to attach the click() event to it?

Comment: Hi @Clijsters. I'd tried call function `BindData` to raised event `grvData_RowDataBound` for reformat the row to merge the cells like before. but it's not ok. may be i don't understand your comment, if my answer not usefull, please ask me more. Thank you!